# How to switch mapboxgl language in DeckGL

Tags: deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm currently playing around with deck.gl.

Taking the UK accident example (3d-heatmap). How can I change the language used to display the POI in mapboxGL?

Where should I put the mapboxGL equivalent of:

```js
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-lg', 'text-field', '{name_fr}');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly related to the usage of react-map-gl rather than deck.gl, given that's what the example is using.

You can grab the mapbox map instance using the `getMap()` method of the `< MapGL>` component, and call the method to change the layout property:

```js
<MapGL ... ref='map' />

const map = this.refs.map.getMap()
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-lg', 'text-field', '{name_fr}')
```